# jQuery select multiple items based on different attribute

Tags: html, jquery

I want to select multiple items based on data attribute. Each item has different data-id attribute.

```
<div class="foo" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="5"></div>
```

For example, find items with data-id 2,3,5 which means return 3 items (data-id is unique)

Can this be done in one select or do I need to loop all foo and check data-id?

Comment: No selector for this without using a looping method like `filter()` or `each()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter` function as follows:

```js
function getDivs(ids){
     return $('.foo').filter(function() { 
          return ids.includes($(this).data("id"));
     });
}
console.log(getDivs([2,3,5]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" data-id="1"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="foo" data-id="5"></div>
```

Comment: Is this better than looping all foo with each and checking data-id?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe less desirable, but it is definitely possible to do this with a single selector:

```
$('.foo[data-id="2"],.foo[data-id="3"],.foo[data-id="5"]')
```

If the list of IDs will likely change, or contains more than a couple of IDs, then Majed Badawi's answer is better.